Setting the shortcut of MacOS Mission Control with default write shell command?
I am used to displaying MacOS Mission Control windows with a middle click (mouse 3) but MacOS Sequoia 15.1 and 15.2 do not save the Mission Control display setting with the mouse "Desktop and Dock > Mission Control > Shortcuts". At each startup, the setting is lost and reverts to its default value.
Is it possible to change this value with a shell command default write to be launched at startup with an Applescript?

Sorry if it is not the right place to ask but it's about MacOS shell commands (programming a workaround to an OS bug).

Great point! Hope you get an answer :)
